# Applying for UK visa in US, but bought the ground UPS return label

Tags: visas, uk

I am applying for a UK tourist visa in the US, and I directly purchase the return label in the UPS rather than from the VFS, which I believe it's fine. But I just realized they might not accept "ground service" and I bought a UPS GROUND COMMERCIAL return label.

In their [guidance for applying for the UK visa](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa):

> "To have your documents returned you must provide a fully addressed prepaid electronic shipping label (we cannot accept ground services and non-electronic waybills). Put your return shipping label and envelope inside the package, and keep a copy of the waybill for your records."

Did anybody have the same situation? Is that acceptable? Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking if the (pretty explicit) `"we cannot accept ground services"` in the guidance is wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I successfully received the passport and the visa. It seems like the type of return label does not matter.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I don't see the word "ground" in the guidance.  Has the guidance changed?

Comment: It's in the question's quote, in parentheses: "we cannot accept ground services and non-electronic waybills" which is "in [the] guidance for applying for the UK visa". @phoog

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas aha, thank you, I don't know how I overlooked that.  At any rate, the current text is "To have your passport or any other documents returned, you must provide a fully addressed UPS prepaid electronic shipping label as we cannot accept non-electronic shipping labels. You must your return shipping label is inside the package, and to keep a copy of the shipping label for your records," so it seems that they've corrected that apparent error, but not without introducing another error.

Comment: Heaven forbid they publish complete and accurate guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Go return the label. You should be able to get a refund, as long as it has not been used to ship anything.

You can then get a 2nd Day Air or Next Day Air label.